# Delphi - Change Editor Background Color in Seattle

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-10-seattle

In previous Delphi versions it was enough to change this back background color setting in options:

[image: option]

however in Seattle there is still this white area at the bottom.

For example in XE8 everything gets colored:

[image: xe8]

and now in Seattle:

[image: seattle]

am i missing something obvious here?

Comment: Use RRUZ's ide theme editor https://github.com/RRUZ/delphi-ide-theme-editor or the ide colorizer https://github.com/RRUZ/Delphi-IDE-Colorizer

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Why should i use extra software for something the IDE could do native all the time?

Comment: It depends on whether or not you want to fix this or not. Feel free not to use @RRUZ's software if you are happy with the IDE as it stands.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan David i used the Theme Editor you linked and then used the regedit keys created to theme it without further using of the tool.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the Editor Syntax Highlight editor is completely broken in Delphi 10 Seattle.  As to why anyone should *dare* complain at having to use 3rd party tools to do what the IDE should (and claims to) do "out of the box", I would point to the price of the product.  Even at 1/10th the price, there would be a reasonable expectation not only that it will do what it claims but that things that used to work will continue to work.  At the price that is being charged, fundamental issues such as this are not just embarrassing but downright insulting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it's because Delphi is now more connected to Windows, i.e. the problem with Page Control being white! I fixed this by Control Panel - Window Color and Appearance - Advanced appearance settings, I then selected the Window Text and set the colour I wanted. This changed the colours default in Delphi. So I just reset the background colour to default and I now have a subtle background green for everything. I have literally just done this, so I need to go play with it further, but it's a start.